# Tutorial information bubble

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface, tooltip

Anyone know how i can create this kind of a tooltip. I need it to contain a TextView and an ImageView in it. Is there a library for this because I couldn't find one.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Tooltip]